# Return IAsyncEnumerable from an async method

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-8.0, iasyncenumerable

Take the following the methods:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
   await SomeAsyncMethod();
   return Bar(); // Throws since you can not return values from iterators
}

public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Bar()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       await Task.Delay(100);
       yield return i;
   }
}
```

I wonder what the best practice would be, to do, what the code above tries to. Basically returning an `IAsyncEnumerable` from an `async` method.

For myself I can imagine two ways:

1. Iterating over the `IAsyncEnumerable` and yielding the result immediately back.

```cs
await foreach(var item in Bar())
{
    yield return item;
}
```

2. Creating a struct which can store an `IAsyncEnumerable` temporarily, which seems to be the better solution, but still kind of overkill.

```cs
return new AsyncEnumerableHolder<int>(Bar());

public struct AsyncEnumerableHolder<T>
{
    public readonly IAsyncEnumerable<T> Enumerable;

    public AsyncEnumerableHolder(IAsyncEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        Enumerable = enumerable;
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Pretty sure `async` expects you to return `void`, `Task`, or `Task<T>` (`void` is almost always the wrong choice there though)

Comment: Well `public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Bar()` is totally valid in terms of syntax. I am not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `async` only supports [certain return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types).  Having `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` as the return type *should* be a compiler error as it doesn't declare a `GetAwaiter` method.

Comment: This is another question of I absolutely need X because I think it's the answer to my problem, however, X doesn't work. Instead, you should explain what are you trying to achieve, there is certainly an alternative.

Comment: @Powerlord Well, `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` and `IAsyncEnumerator<T>` return types are definitely supported in C#8 - [Asynchronous streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#asynchronous-streams)

Comment: @IvanStoev In that case, I've filed a ticket against the page I previously linked commenting on the missing documentation.

Comment: @Powerlord That MSDN page has been updated to add: "Starting with C# 8.0, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, for an async method that returns an async stream."

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The struct approach wouldn't work. If you want to asynchronously return an `IAsyncEnumerator<T>` value, you *could* use `Task<IAsyncEnumerator<T>>` with `return Bar();`. However, that would be unusual. It would be much more natural to create a new `IAsyncEnumerator<T>` that incorporates `await SomeAsyncMethod()` at the beginning of the asynchronous enumerable. To do this, you should use `await` and `yield` as suggested by your option (1):

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
  await SomeAsyncMethod();
  await foreach (var item in Bar())
    yield return item;
}
```

On a side note, JavaScript has a very nice `yield*` syntax for this kind of "enumerate this whole sequence into my result sequence" concept, and it supports both synchronous and asynchronous sequences. C# does not have this kind of syntax for either synchronous or asynchronous sequences.

Comment: Thanks for that one, it just feels so wrong to iterate it again. I really hope the `yield*` thingy or similar will every arrive to C#.

Comment: @Twenty: You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/378) if you're interested.