# Why am I not allowed to return an IAsyncEnumerable in a method returning an IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, iasyncenumerable

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IValidationSystem<T>
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(T obj);
}
```

And I am trying to implement it this way:

```
public class Foo
{ }

public class Bar
{ }

public class BarValidationSystem : IValidationSystem<T>
{   
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(Bar bar)
    {
        var foo = await GetRequiredThingAsync();

        return GetErrors(bar, foo).Select(e => new ValidationResult(e)).ToAsyncEnumerable();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetErrors(Bar bar, Foo foo)
    {
        yield return "Something is wrong";
        yield return "Oops something else is wrong";
        yield return "And eventually, this thing is wrong too";
    }
    
    private Task<Foo> GetRequiredThingAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new Foo());
    }
}
```

But this does not compile:

> CS1622    Cannot return a value from an iterator. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration.

I know I can fix by iterating the enumerable:

```
foreach (var error in GetErrors(bar, foo))
{
    yield return new ValidationResult(error);
}
```

Or by returning a `Task<IEnumerable<ValidationResult>>`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ValidationResult>> ValidateAsync(Bar bar)
{
    var foo = await GetRequiredThingAsync;

    return GetErrors(bar, foo).Select(e => new ValidationResult(e));
}
```

But I would like to understand why I cannot return an `IAsyncEnumerable` in my case. When writing "classic" `IEnumerable` methods, you can either return an `IEnumerable` or yield return several values. Why am I not allowed to do the same with `IAsyncEnumerable`?

Comment: I tried to look at this, but there are too many things missing to make this compile. Can you provide a [mcve] (ideally with a fiddle link)?

Comment: @Heinzi: I added some stuff. I think it will compile right now

Comment: As the error suggests, you need to use `yield return...`. So drop the `ToAsyncEnumerable` and instead loop over the result of the `Select` and yield return every item.

Comment: @DavidG: I don't think that answers the question: *"But I would like to understand why I cannot return an IAsyncEnumerable in my case."*

Comment: @Heinzi Nope, that's why I wrote a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @fharreau: Nope, fiddle still misses the definition for `ToAsyncEnumerable()`. Sorry, I'm out... too much work getting it to compile (need to return to work).

Comment: @DavidG: Ah, ok.

Comment: @DavidG: I am aware of that solution as I said in my question (and showed the code). I just want to know why. When writing "classic" IEnumerable methods, you can either return an IEnumerable or yield return value. Why am I not allowed to do the same with IAsyncEnumerable?

Comment: Related: [Pass-through for IAsyncEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876417/pass-through-for-iasyncenumerable)

Comment: This looks like a bug or at least an unintentional limitation, when reading the [spec proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/async-streams#syntax-1). The intent was clearly for an async iterator to be signaled by the use of `yield`, just like sync iterators; yet the mere combination of `async` and the return type seems to lock it in as an iterator.

Comment: @Jeroen: That's my understanding of the situation. Thank you for putting this into a clear sentence!

Comment: @Heinzi: looks like fiddle is not up to date to use this new feature. I can't get it compiling neither. `IAsyncEnumerable` is part of  the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Comment: Another related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689529/return-iasyncenumerable-from-an-async-method

Comment: @fharreau - I've got it compiling in .NET Fiddle: you must include the nuget package `System.Interactive.Async`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This looks like a bug or at least an unintentional limitation, when reading the [spec proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/async-streams#syntax-1).

The spec states that the presence of `yield` results in an iterator method; and the presence of both `async` and `yield` results in an asynchronous iterator method.

> But I would like to understand why I cannot return an IAsyncEnumerable in my case.

The `async` keyword is making this into an asynchronous iterator method. Since you need the `async` for the `await`, then you'll need to use `yield` as well.

> When writing "classic" IEnumerable methods, you can either return an IEnumerable or yield return several values. Why am I not allowed to do the same with IAsyncEnumerable?

With both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, you can perform synchronous work before returning the enumerable directly. In this case, the method is not special at all; it just does some work and then returns a value to its caller.

But you can't do asynchronous work before returning an asynchronous enumerator. In this case, you need the `async` keyword. Adding the `async` keyword forces the method to either be an asynchronous method or an asynchronous iterator method.

To put it another way, all methods can be classified into these different types in C#:

- Normal methods. No `async` or `yield` present.
- Iterator methods. A `yield` in the body without `async`. Must return `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IEnumerator<T>`).
- Asynchronous methods. An `async` is present without `yield`. Must return a tasklike.
- Asynchronous iterator methods. Both `async` and `yield` are present. Must return `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` (or `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`).

From yet another perspective, consider the state machine that must be used to implement such a method, and especially think about when the `await GetRequiredThingAsync()` code runs.

In the synchronous world *without* `yield`, `GetRequiredThing()` would run *before* returning the enumerable. In the synchronous world *with* `yield`, `GetRequiredThing()` would run when the first item of the enumerable is requested.

In the asynchronous world *without* `yield`, `await GetRequiredThingAsync()` would run *before* returning the async enumerable (and in that case, the return type would be `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>`, since you have to do asynchronous work to *get* the async enumerable). In the asynchronous world *with* `yield`, `await GetRequiredThingAsync()` would run when the first item of the enumerable is requested.

Generally speaking, the only case when you want to do work before returning the enumerable is when you're doing precondition checks (which are synchronous by nature). Doing an API/DB call is not normal; most of the time the expected semantics are that any API/DB calls will be done as part of *enumeration*. In other words, even the synchronous code probably *should have been* using `foreach` and `yield`, just like the asynchronous code is *forced* to do.

On a side note, it would be nice in these scenarios to have a `yield*` for both synchronous and asynchronous iterators, but C# does not support that.

Answer (score 5):

The usual syntax for an async method is to return a Task:

```
public async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync()
{
    /...
}
```

If you make it `async` but not return a `Task<T>` then the compiler will flag an error in the header.

There is an exception: an iterator method that returns `IAsyncEnumerable`

```
private static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> ThisShouldReturnAsTask()
{
    yield return 0;
    await Task.Delay(100);
    yield return 1;
}
```

In your example, you have an async function that returns `IAsyncEnumerable`, but is NOT an iterator. (It just returns a straight enumerable object, instead of yielding values one-by-one.)

Hence the error: "Cannot return a value from an iterator"

If you changed the signature to return `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<ValidationResult>>`

```
public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<ValidationResult>> ValidateAsync(Bar bar)
{
    var foo = await GetRequiredThingAsync();
    return GetErrors(bar, foo).Select(e => new ValidationResult(e)).ToAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

then you will need to change the way you invoke it: it would have to be

```
await foreach(var f in await ValidateAsync(new Bar()))
```

Instead of

```
await foreach(var f in ValidateAsync(new Bar()))
```

See examples to play with here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yPTdqp

Comment: Nop, absolutely not. It is possible to return an async IAsyncEnumerable<T>, check the new C# 8 features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8#a-tour-through-async-enumerables

Comment: @fharreau: OK, I wasn't aware of this. But in these examples, it's an iterator method. My guess is that if it's not returning a Task then it is an iterator method. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: That would work. But I don't want to modify this interface. I know how to fix the compilation as I said in the question, but I want to understand why I can't just return an `IAsyncEnumerable`.

Comment: @fharreau - I've modified the answer based on the link you've sent. (I've learned a lot out of being wrong this evening  :-)

Comment: A method returning a `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<...>>` is not the same thing as one returning an `IAsyncEnumerable`, even if the latter method is `async`. A method returning `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<...>>` cannot be used in an `await foreach`; the result of that method would itself need to be awaited.

Comment: The true issue here is that the use of the `async` keyword in the method signature turn the method into an `iterator method` (probably not the right wording for it), forcing the uses of `yield return` (check the 2 answers of Stephen Cleary in the linked questions)

Comment: @fharreau Thanks for posting the question. My answer generated interesting comments so I'll leave it here rather than deleting it.